# Why does cups get updated so often?

Tags: apt, package-management

Almost every time I get a software update, I see CUPS, or packages with `cups` in their names, being updated.

Is that normal? It seems that this has been happening for years, regardless of the Ubuntu version I run. I've always been curious, as CUPS seems to be on fire, far more active than any other F/LOSS project.

Comment: At a guess it is because it seems to have been purchased and developed by Apple for Mac and other Unix-like systems (including Linux). So more money can be poured into its development that most open-source projects.

Answer (score 20):

CUPS is an acronym for Common Unix Printing System. So when a new printer comes out, it needs to be added to the database (one portion of the update). If it uses the same commands as a previous printer from the manufacturer, then the drivers are already in the database, otherwise new drivers are needed (second portion of the update).

Comment: Kind of makes you wish that the architecture was based on a central printer repository from which it would query info and download drivers.

Answer (score 7):

At a guess it is because it seems to have been purchased and developed by Apple for Mac and other Unix-like systems (including Linux).

Since it is funded by a company — not grants, fund raising, etc., more money can be poured into its development than most open source projects.

You can find some more information [on the CUPS Developer Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906233428/https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/spec-cmp.html) and [on the CUPS Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS).

Comment: Seems like unfounded speculation; could you add some evidence? Active development would result in more releases and more features, but not necessarily more security updates. Routine APT updates aren't supposed to add features.

Comment: I think @LD3's [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/647529/44630)  is much more convincing.  There are lots of software packages with substantial commercial backing but they don't churn out updates every week or so like cups.

Comment: I think we've got some traction from reviewers to reopen this question which I don't think is opinion-based.